# React Router pass route parameter from parent to child

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have created a wrapper around the Route component in react called PrivateRoute.

I want to be able to call a Page component from inside of this and pass the :id of the path to it, so this is how i call it:

```js
 <PrivateRoute exact path="/page/:id"
   render={() => <Page secure={true} resource="/pages/" />}/>
```

But inside of the Page component where i want to access the route param.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getEntity(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
```

this.props.match.params.id shows as undefined.

Previously i had this:

```js
<PrivateRoute path="/pages/:id" component={Page} />
```

and Page received the id. via this.props.match.params.id
but then i don't know how i can pass other props to the page which is why i changed it.

This is the implementatio of my Route wrapper

```js
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn, children, ...rest } = this.props;
    const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
    if (loggedIn == "true") {
      return <Route {...rest}>{children}</Route>;
    } else {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { referrer: this.props.location }
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how i am supposed to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself: "What's 'this'?". In the context of:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getEntity(this.props.match.params.id);
}
```

`this.props` doesn't belong to properties coming from `PrivateRoute` component.

Solution:

Add prop `id` to `Page` component and pass the id like this:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/page/:id"
   render={({ match }) => <Page secure={true} resource="/pages/" id={match.params.id} />}/>
```

Comment: One thing i still don't understand though, how did you know you could pass match to the render? Could you please explain or do you know of a link?

Comment: @Amir The React Router docs have a section on the 'match' object and where it can be accessed: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match.